# CakePHP, Is it possible to use a record id in the front of the url

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, routes, redirect

I need to set a record id in the url for all my pages. For example, if the user does not supply the id the site should always use 1000 as the default eg. http:// www.demosite.com/1000.

If the user navigates to http:// www.demosite.com/1001 I set record 1001 details in a session and display it in an element. From here on forward I need all the urls to look like this.

http:// www.demosite.com/1001/about-us

http:// www.demosite.com/1001/wizard/step1

http:// www.demosite.com/1001/prices/view/1

I have tried the route below, which works but I need to redirect and then I lose the 1001 record id in the url.

```
Router::connect('/:id', array('controller' => 'distributors', 'action' => 'session'), array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
Router::connect('/:id/**', array('controller' => 'distributors', 'action' => 'session'), array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: You want to implement caekphp same like  `Localization`  feature  ??

Comment: Yes, but with a random record id.

Answer (score 0):

You taken it bit complicated, you just need to pass it in the method in controller, define 1000 default there and then other parameters.

```
function index($id=1000){

}
```

when you will pass new id into method that will over right new one

And along with these you can also use htaccess to work with other url locations
like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([0-9]{6})$ scriptname.php?no=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

You can take help from http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html